# Chartjs to show more set of data of click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have created a bar chart using `chart.js` and I need to show only few set of data on first load and if there are more than say 6 datas available, we should show the more button and on click to that button, we should show all the remaining data.

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/moviecrew/wk1aejso/8/

I have tried to create a new variable with all the data and slicing them to show only number of data:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 5 ; i++) {
  campSourceLabels.push[campSourceLabelsAll[i]];
  campSourceLabels.push[campSourceDataTvAll[i]];
  campSourceLabels.push[campSourceDataTlAll[i]];
  campSourceLabels.push[campSourceDataCrAll[i]];
}
```

where `campSourceLabelsAll` would have all the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution. You keep all your data in your variables and show only a few of you data at the start. When you click the button you change the displayed data. 
I always keep my data and options in seperate variables for an easier access.

Important Code (without `options`, colors and comments) [(complete code with live preview here (JSBin))](https://jsbin.com/yuluyafoqa/1/edit?html,js,output):

```
var campSourceLabels = ["Facebook", "Google", "Landing \nPage", "Email \nCampaign", "Alt landing \npage", "Forum \nLink"];
var campSourceDataTv = [64, 66, 99, 76, 59, 76];
var campSourceDataTl = [36, 53, 76, 70, 55, 89];
var campSourceDataCr = [47, 47, 69, 47, 47, 47];
var displayCount = 4

function showAllData() {
  chartData.labels = campSourceLabels
  chartData.datasets[0].data = campSourceDataTv
  chartData.datasets[1].data = campSourceDataTl
  chartData.datasets[2].data = campSourceDataCr
  chart2.update()
}

var chartData = {
  labels: campSourceLabels.slice(0, displayCount),
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Total Visitors',
    data: campSourceDataTv.slice(0, displayCount)
  }, {
    label: 'Total Leads',
    data: campSourceDataTl.slice(0, displayCount)
  }, {
    label: 'Conversion rate',
    data: campSourceDataCr.slice(0, displayCount)
  }]
}
var chartOptions = { ... }

var ctx = document.getElementById('chart2').getContext('2d');
window.chart2 = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: chartData,
  options: chartOptions
});
```

Comment: thank you. that's exactly what i was looking for. but again, when the data adds, is there any way that the height of each bar remains the same and the whole canvas height increases, so if there are 100s of data, it won't look bad.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/moviecrew/wk1aejso/15/ here is the updated fiddle with problem

Comment: Do you want something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/gj1bxyz0/

Comment: yeah like that. but how did you manage to calculate the height? be advised, the height of each bar can be different in different chart. this is just the reference so we can't use static height for bar. just want to understand how this is working. I didn't understand the value `100` you've used

Comment: The heigth of 100 is only approximately. You can try to get all the heigths of the bars, the space between them, the scale, the scale labels, the legend, ..., but that's out of my reach and time. You can't update the size of a canvas, you have to delete and redraw it. So it's a completly new canvas and chart. It's not that easy to match everything...

Comment: Same for the overhead like scale, scale labels and legend. That's the `+1`. Approximately 100 pixels for that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203164/discussion-between-lucian-and-headhunterkev).